# Pandas fillna() in DataFrame not working with inplace = True

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the Titanic dataset from Kaggle and I'm trying to replace the NA values with 30, when the Pclass is 2. I've tried the following code, but value 30 doesn't seem to be saved in the dataframe.

`data[data['Pclass']==2].fillna({'Age':30}, inplace = True)`

The expected result should bee that all NA values in Pclass = 2 will be replaced with 30. But when I checke again, I still see NA Values.

`data[data['Pclass']==2]`

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro4Mf.png)

Why doesn't inplace = True allowing me to save the replaced values in the original dataframe?

Comment: The image on "Ouput" is what I get after running data[data['Pclass']==2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sygneto mentioned, you are filling na to a subset of your data - it won't touch the original data.You know, when you get the warning *SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame*.

I would personally locate the columns I want updated and would do it on a column basis. Something like:

```
data.loc[(data['Pclass']==2) & (data['Age'].isnull()),'Age']=30
```

Comment: Ok, then I think I wrongly underestood inplace=True. I thought I would be rewriting my original DataFrame and not creating a copy. Does it mean that I am creating a copy every time I set inplace = True?

Comment: No, if you simply do df.fillna(30,inplace=True) then it would modify the original dataframe. But if you do df[df['Pclass==2]] -> That's a view or a copy of your dataframe so df[df['Pclass==2]].fillna(0,inplace=True) would modify inplace that copy of your dataframe...not your original df. So to modify the original df we can do instead df.loc[.....]= something . Does that make sense ?

Comment: glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

you are working on the copy, use inplace with loc, create new var and then use inplace, in general dont use inplace in future

```
df=data.loc[data['Pclass']==2]
df.fillna({'Age':30}, inplace = True)
```